# Conditionally invoke action methods with same URL and Http Verb

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I would like to create 2 action methods with same URL and Http Verb but conditionally invoke only one of them to the Web API framework based on a boolean flag. What would be the best way to achieve this?

```csharp
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/data/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostV1(long id, RequestDTO1 v1) {

    }


   [HttpPost]
   [Route("api/data/{id}")]
   public HttpResponseMessage PostV2(long id, RequestDTO2 v2) {

   }
```

Either PostV1 or PostV2 should be invoked based on a boolean flag at runtime. The boolean flag will either be a feature flag or a config flag. I cannot update the URLs to contain the flag. That is not under my control.

Comment: Where do you intend to pass the flag exactly? Or is it in config?

Comment: Yes, it is either a feature flag or a config flag on the server side. I cannot update the URL, it is not under my control.

Comment: Can you use inheritance for `RequestDTO1` and `RequestDTO2`?

Comment: @govin Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar scenario with feature flags. The feature flags contain logic that eventually depends on information inside the request context, so the "boolean" in question must be some kind of hook that has access to the request context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the version is governed by a config switch that is read at startup time, you can remove the RouteAttribute from your action methods and instead define the routing in your `global.asax.cs` or `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` (or whatever it is your site uses). Use a simple `if` condition to define a different routing under different circumstances.

```
if (configSwitch)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Custom",
        "api/data/{id}",
         new { 
                 controller = "MyController", 
                 action = "PostV1"
             }
    );
}
else
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Custom",
        "api/data/{id}",
         new { 
                 controller = "MyController", 
                 action = "PostV2"  //Notice the version difference
             }
    );
}
```

Or (slightly shorter):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Custom",
    "api/data/{id}",
     new { 
             controller = "MyController", 
             action = configSwitch ? "PostV1" : "PostV2"
         }
);
```

See [this knowledge base article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#routes) for more information.

Comment: That would work, any chance this could be done through attribute routing?

Comment: Not with the default implementation. You can't extend `RouteAttribute` because it is sealed, and the default doesn't know anything about your configuration switch. But you could extend [UrlRoutingModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule(v=vs.110).aspx) and put whatever logic you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "flag" is sent in the URL, yes? So why not just put it in the route?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/data/v1/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostV1(long id, RequestDTO1 v1) {

}


[HttpPost]
[Route("api/data/v2/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostV2(long id, RequestDTO2 v2) {

}
```

Comment: I thought along the same lines but the OP insists that the routes should remain the same.

Comment: The flag is not sent in the URL. The flag will either be a feature flag or a config flag on the server side. I cannot update the URL, it is not under my control.